# Magento 2 - How to disable customer account by code script or function?

Tags: magento2, customer

In magento2, how to disable customer account by code script for an action or what existing function do this(disable).

Comment: Specify, what action you need to restict when account is disabling?

Comment: i havent tried but you can disable customer module from xml file.